# Get Web data with images for HTML table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the article body with images from [this link](https://www.cnbc.com/2022/01/03/5-ways-to-reset-your-retirement-savings-and-save-more-money-in-2022.html), so that using the extracted article body I can make a HTML table. So, I have tried using `BeautifulSoup`.

```
t_link = 'https://www.cnbc.com/2022/01/03/5-ways-to-reset-your-retirement-savings-and-save-more-money-in-2022.html'
page = requests.get(t_link)
soup_page = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')


html_article = soup_page.find_all("div", {"class": re.compile('ArticleBody-articleBody.?')})


for article_body in html_article: 
  print(article_body)
```

But unfortunately the `article_body` didn't show any image, like this. Because, `<div class="InlineImage-wrapper">` is't scraping in this way

[image]

So, how can I get article data with article images, so that I can make a HTML table?

Comment: it seems that the site uses a lazy loading method to load the images, which means it's loaded when the page is rendered, I think bs4 cannot handle that since it doesn't render the page (it only scrapes the source page, not the rendered page)

Comment: There is a `<div class="InlineImage-wrapper">` for image, I am beginner in scraping, so I am facing problem to sole this

Comment: yes, as I told you, the HTML tag for the image is there, but the image is not loaded on the server side, it 's rendered on client side (it uses lazy loading), bs4 can't retrieve the images directly since it doesn't render the images. I tried checking the page, there is still a way to use bs4, but you need to use the ID from e.g. `id="ArticleBody-InlineImage-106967852"` = `106967852`, and find its mapping on the `window.__s_data`, once you found the mapping, get the image from that object

Comment: I am at a loss to understand in what way getting an image (lazy loading, Requests doesn't see it because it's loading dynamically from a different source, which exists however in an `ld+json` script tag, etc - see @baduker's response) will contribute toward a HTML table...? You scrape data to do stuffs with it, analyse it, whatever, not 'scrape HTML to create HTML... table'. No offense, but there are serious logical gaps in your question.

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus Yes, Actually, I am a beginner (not a developer or like this), I am searching if there is a way to scrape the article content ( with all paragraphs and images) .  I thought almost everything can be scrapped and in python there is plenty of libraries to do these types of stuff , that is unknown to me, anyone may solve my issue.  I got an idea from baduker's response, especially thanks to him. From his response, I am trying to solve my issue in another way. Also, thanks a lot  Barry for your kind response.

Comment: > You scrape data to do stuffs with it, analyse it, whatever, not 'scrape HTML to create HTML... table'. @BarrythePlatipus That's what "reader mode" on Chrome, iOS, etc. is. :)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't quite understand your goal, so mine is probably not the answer you want.

In the html source of that page you have all inside the script you at the bottom.

[image]

It has inside the content of the page in JSON format.
If you simply use `grep` and `jq` (a great JSON cli utility), you can run

```bash
curl -kL "https://www.cnbc.com/2022/01/03/5-ways-to-reset-your-retirement-savings-and-save-more-money-in-2022.html" | \
grep -Po '"body":.+"body".' | \
grep -Po '{"content":\[.+"body".' | \
jq '[.content[]|select(.tagName|contains("image"))]'
```

to have all infos about the images

```json
[
  {
    "tagName": "image",
    "attributes": {
      "id": "106967852",
      "type": "image",
      "creatorOverwrite": "PM Images",
      "headline": "Retirement Savings",
      "url": "https://image.cnbcfm.com/api/v1/image/106967852-1635524865061-GettyImages-1072593728.jpg?v=1635525026",
      "datePublished": "2021-10-29T16:30:26+0000",
      "copyrightHolder": "PM Images",
      "width": "2233",
      "height": "1343"
    },
    "data": {
      "__typename": "image"
    },
    "children": [],
    "__typename": "bodyContent"
  },
  {
    "tagName": "image",
    "attributes": {
      "id": "106323101",
      "type": "image",
      "creatorOverwrite": "JGI/Jamie Grill",
      "headline": "GP: 401k money jar on desk of businesswoman",
      "url": "https://image.cnbcfm.com/api/v1/image/106323101-1578344280328gettyimages-672157227.jpeg?v=1641216437",
      "datePublished": "2020-01-06T20:58:19+0000",
      "copyrightHolder": "JGI/Jamie Grill",
      "width": "5120",
      "height": "3418"
    },
    "data": {
      "__typename": "image"
    },
    "children": [],
    "__typename": "bodyContent"
  }
]
```

If you need only the URLs, run

```bash
curl -kL "https://www.cnbc.com/2022/01/03/5-ways-to-reset-your-retirement-savings-and-save-more-money-in-2022.html" | \
grep -Po '"body":.+"body".' | \
grep -Po '{"content":\[.+"body".' | \
jq  -r '[.content[]|select(.tagName|contains("image"))]|.[].attributes.url'
```

to get

```
https://image.cnbcfm.com/api/v1/image/106967852-1635524865061-GettyImages-1072593728.jpg?v=1635525026
https://image.cnbcfm.com/api/v1/image/106323101-1578344280328gettyimages-672157227.jpeg?v=1641216437
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything you want is in the source `HTML`, but you need to jump through a couple of hoops to get that data.

I'm providing the following:

- article body
- two (2) images that go with the article body and a url to header video (1)

Here's how:

```py
import json
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0",
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    url = "https://www.cnbc.com/2022/01/03/5-ways-to-reset-your-retirement-savings-and-save-more-money-in-2022.html"
    script = [
        s.text for s in
        BeautifulSoup(s.get(url).text, "lxml").find_all("script")
        if "window.__s_data" in s.text
    ][0]
    payload = json.loads(
        re.match(r"window\.__s_data=(.*);\swindow\.__c_data=", script).group(1)
    )
    article_data = (
        payload
        ["page"]
        ["page"]
        ["layout"][3]
        ["columns"][0]
        ["modules"][2]
        ["data"]
    )
    print(article_data["articleBodyText"])
    for item in article_data["body"]["content"]:
        if "url" in item["attributes"].keys():
            print(item["attributes"]["url"])
```

This should print:

1. The entire article body (*Redacted for brevity*)

```
The new year offers opportunities for many Americans in their careers and financial lives. The "Great Reshuffle" is expected to continue as employees leave jobs and take new ones at a rapid clip. At the same time, many workers have made a vow to save more this year, yet many admit they don't know how they'll stick to that goal. One piece of advice: Keep it simple. 
[...]
```

The above mentioned urls to assets:

```
https://www.cnbc.com/video/2022/01/03/how-to-choose-the-best-retirement-strategy-for-2022.html
https://image.cnbcfm.com/api/v1/image/106967852-1635524865061-GettyImages-1072593728.jpg?v=1635525026
https://image.cnbcfm.com/api/v1/image/106323101-1578344280328gettyimages-672157227.jpeg?v=1641216437
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to download the images, use this:

```py
import json
import os
import re
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import copyfileobj

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0",
}

url = "https://www.cnbc.com/2022/01/03/5-ways-to-reset-your-retirement-savings-and-save-more-money-in-2022.html"


def download_images(image_source: str, directory: str) -> None:
    """Download images from a given source and save them to a given directory."""
    os.makedirs(directory, exist_ok=True)
    save_dir = Path(directory)
    if re.match(r".*\.jp[e-g]", image_source):
        file_name = save_dir / image_source.split("/")[-1].split("?")[0]
        with s.get(image_source, stream=True) as img, open(file_name, "wb") as output:
            copyfileobj(img.raw, output)


with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    script = [
        s.text for s in
        BeautifulSoup(s.get(url).text, "lxml").find_all("script")
        if "window.__s_data" in s.text
    ][0]
    payload = json.loads(
        re.match(r"window\.__s_data=(.*);\swindow\.__c_data=", script).group(1)
    )
    article_data = (
        payload
        ["page"]
        ["page"]
        ["layout"][3]
        ["columns"][0]
        ["modules"][2]
        ["data"]
    )
    print(article_data["articleBodyText"])
    for item in article_data["body"]["content"]:
        if "url" in item["attributes"].keys():
            url = item["attributes"]["url"]
            print(url)
            download_images(url, "images")
```